# getting "read property 'length' of undefined" when try to enter date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-bootstrap

could you please tell me why i am getting this error .

```
angular.js:12798 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at parseDateString (VM651 ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js:3037)
    at Array.parseDate (VM651 ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js:3062)
    at NgModelController.$$parseAndValidate (VM647 angular.js:25837)
    at NgModelController.$commitViewValue (VM647 angular.js:25827)
    at VM647 angular.js:25970
    at ChildScope.$eval (VM647 angular.js:16374)
    at ChildScope.$apply (VM647 angular.js:16474)
    at NgModelController.$$debounceViewValueCommit (VM647 angular.js:25969)
    at NgModelController.$setViewValue (VM647 angular.js:25941)
    at HTMLInputElement.listener (VM647 angular.js:22200)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12798
(anonymous) @ angular.js:9545
$apply @ angular.js:16479
$$debounceViewValueCommit @ angular.js:25969
$setViewValue @ angular.js:25941
listener @ angular.js:22200
dispatch @ jquery.js:5183
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4991
```

Actually I am trying to enter date without using "datepicker" then I get this error why .how to resolve this error

Step to reproduce this error

1. Run the application .First  date field is empty .I just entered `1` inside that then I will get this error why ?

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZG4Inotn7EtVZ5QbCsMH?p=preview

```
$scope.changedate =function(){
    console.log('asda')
  }
```

i also didn't get changed event .

I am making datepicker from here 
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've chosen to supply a collection of alternate date formats but you haven't properly mapped it in your HTML.

Specifically,

```
<input type="text" ng-change='changedate()' class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="x.name" is-open="x.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="formats" />
```

You were mapping `alt-input-formats` to `altInputFormats`, which isn't defined.

[Here's an updated Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/L7zHhKBxx6vlj0pHUyhX?p=preview)

Comment: can I get any event when user select date from date picker ?

Comment: You mean to receive the `Date` value as an argument in your `changedate()` handler? Sure. Just make sure you're passing it in your HTML (i.e. `ng-change="changedate(x.name)"`), then do what you need with it inside of `changedate()`.